# При запросе к MSSQL выдает ошибку

Tags: c#, sql-server

Я начинающий программист.
При выполнении `command2.ExecuteNonQuery();` падает в ошибку:

> Activated  Event   Time    Duration    Thread
>   Exception: Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Data.dll ("Существует >назначенный этой команде Command открытый DataReader, который требуется предварительно закрыть.").

```
try
{
    using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand($"select name from Table ", sqlcon))
    {
        com.CommandTimeout = 60;
        using (SqlDataReader sqlReader = com.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (sqlReader.Read())
            {
                tblInfo2.NAME = (sqlReader[1]).ToString();
                tblInfo2.RO2 = ((int)sqlReader[0]).ToString();

                if (current_table == tblInfo2.NAME || Local_RO != tblInfo2.RO2)
                {

                        SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(zapro, sqlcon);
                        SqlParameter tblParam = new SqlParameter("@id_table", tblInfo2.ID);
                        SqlParameter wroParam = new SqlParameter("@wro", Local_RO);
                        command2.Parameters.Add(tblParam);
                        command2.Parameters.Add(roParam);
                        command2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего у Вас один и тот же **sqlcon** используется для нескольких ридеров. Создайте новый SqlConnection, например:

```
try
{
       using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand($"select name from Table ", conn))
       {
          ...
         using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Ваша строка подключения"))
         {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(zapro, conn);
            ...
         }
       }
}
catch (Exception ex) { }
```